# What http code should a server respond with when it is being updated and partially available?

Tags: http, http-status-codes

When updating my website, I shift the server into "update" mode. Any requests for the main domain (example.com), result in a static page saying the site is being updated. But how does one respond to other requests, such as images, form submissions etc, which are normally valid, but are in the process of being updated ?

Which HTTP code should be returned so the client knows that the request is temporarily unavailable ?

4XX is not suitable, because it is not a user error.
5XX seems unsuitable, because there isn't an internal error. It is intentionally not serving any requests except for displaying a maintenance page

3XX seems unsuitable because the files (images, pages etc), are not moving anywhere. They are just temporarily inaccessible.

Perhaps to better understand what I'm saying, if you've ever visited the apple website during a Keynote, they take it offline for maintenance and display a yellow "sticky" image saying they will be back soon.

EDIT: For the main page I don't want to return a 503, because it won't display in the browser. But for other assets that are being updated it makes sense.

Comment: What's wrong with 503?

Comment: Well I wan't to serve the main page with a message saying the site is being updated, but don't wan't to send a 503 because then people might think the site is down, as 503's don't render in the browser. I guess it makes sense to send a 503 just for the assets that are changing, but not for the main page.

Comment: I don't think that's a problem. You can have pages with error status that still show HTML.

Comment: When the error is 4xx (client error), I've seen pages being rendered. But in the case of 5xx I haven't. So I guess for all assets I should just return a 503, but for the main page a 200

Comment: That is not a good idea. If that page wanted to display any images (logos, banners, etc), it would not be able to, and all the user would see is placeholders.  Not a good user experience.

Comment: The maintenance page is a specific page and assets that will never be updated / missing as the same time as other normal assets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HTTP Error 503](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_503) - Service unavailable

> The server is currently unavailable (because it is overloaded or down for maintenance). Generally, this is a temporary state.

Comment: Does it make sense to respond to requests for the main page with 200, and for other assets (that could be updated) with 503 ?

Comment: You can have a 503 main page that still shows a custom HTML maintenance banner.

Comment: 404s are always displayed. But are 503's ? I don't think I've ever seen one that renders in the browser like a regular page.

Comment: I've made these pages for 502. Works fine. Cannot see why it would be different with 503. Also, if you've ever worked with Tomcat, you'll probably have encountered 500 Internal Server error with detailed Java stacktrace info.

Comment: Regardless of the actual status code being reported, most web browsers will look at the `Content-Type` header and render the content if it is a displayable type, even if the status code is an error number. That allows users to see custom error messages that the server wants them to see. Remember, web browsers are primarily intended for **user-based** interactions, whereas status codes are intended for **application-based** interactions. Users don't care about error codes, they care about content. If the server does not provide error content, a web browser may display a generic error message.

Comment: That makes sense. I will use 503.